# flex mobile project :prompt user to turn on gps in android mobile

Tags: android, gps, flex4.5

Is it possible to prompt user to turn on gps of android mobile in flex mobile project. If possible please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to write a native extension.
It´s possible that someone has already done this. You shold google a bit.
If you cant find a native extension which solves this task you have to write your own.
Adobe gives graet documentations of how to do this.

Lee brimlow has also an excellent tutorial about native extensions on his site.
www.gotoandlearn.com

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi I have to do this in flex mobile project not in android project